# scrapy: how to not print everything to screen while scraping

Tags: scrapy

When I am scraping something I see an output to screen of everything that scrapy is pulling. Is there a way to not show this and instead just show some kind of status that the spider is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean the logs, maybe it is setup as `DEBUG` as default, so to just show important scrapy information I think you should set it to `INFO`, just go to `settings.py` and add:

```
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
```